# git ls-files sort by modification time

Tags: git, sorting

How can I list files sorted by their modification time?

I want the git modification time, not the system modification time. For example, if I have a (committed) file `README`, then

```
touch README
```

will change the system modification time... but the git status would remain unchanged.

If I try

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 ls  -t
```

this will sort by the system modification time.

Is there any option to `git ls-files` that would list files sorted by their git modification time?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Is there any option to `git ls-files` that would list files sorted by
>   their git modification time?

I don't think so.  One possible way would be to iterate over the files, get the timestamp using `git log`, and `sort` the output.

The following might work for you:

```
while read file; do echo $(git log --pretty=format:%ad -n 1 --date=raw -- $file) $file; done < <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD) | sort -k1,1n
```

Answer (score 15):

Best answer is by [Mikko Rantalainen](https://serverfault.com/users/104798/mikko-rantalainen) on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1031956/157443):

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD -z | TZ=UTC xargs -0n1 -I_ git --no-pager log -1 --date=iso-local --format="%ad _" -- _ | sort
```

Comment: This is best because it (a) shows human-readable timestamps, unlike devnull 's answer above and (b) shows the timestamps in general, and also more than just the most recent, unlike  datinc 's and thill 's answers above.

Comment: To support cases where files are renamed in git, use this for the xargs bit: `xargs -0n1 -I_ sh -c 'git --no-pager log --follow --date=iso-local --format="%ad _" -- _ | tail -1'`

Comment: "xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value"

Answer (score 8):

Easiest and fastest is probably

```
git diff-index      --name-only --diff-filter=A @
git log --pretty='' --name-only | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

`git diff-index ...` lists all your newly-tracked files first, then `git log ...` lists all files in history most-recently-touched first (`| awk ...` removes duplicates).  It'll still list historical files that have been deleted in the current checkout, but it hardly seems worth the complexity to weed those out.

Comment: `git log --pretty='' --name-only | awk '!seen[$0]++'` is definitely the fastest, but unfortunately it's missing the very useful context of the modification timestamps.

Comment: @ijoseph `git log --first-parent --pretty=%cd --name-status | awk 'NF==1{date=$1}NF>1 && !seen[$2]++{print date,$0}' FS=$'\t'`

Comment: Are you a wizard? Amazing.

Comment: @ijoseph nahhh, that's bread'n'butter stuff.

Comment: much much faster than `git ls-tree`. thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to sort files in a folder by using the following command

```
git ls-files -z -- "${dir}" | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%at {}" {} | sort | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f2-
```

Comment: I needed to sort by creation time, so modified it like this and I think it worked: `git ls-files -z -- "${dir}" | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- sh -c 'git log -1 --format="%at {}" {} | tail -1' | sort | cut -d " " -f2-`

Comment: Running that command on Mac, I get `fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths`

Answer (score 3):

This won't show ALL files, but it does give you a quick idea on what changed in the order your looking for:

```
git log --name-only
```