# List of files sorted by their most recent modification date (git) in human readable format

Tags: git, shell, zsh

Say we are in a git repo with several folders and files. I am hoping to get a list of ***all files*** in the repo and their most recent modification timestamp in **human readable format**.

The list should be  **sorted** by this modification timestamp.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

I am assuming `git ls-files` could be used for this but haven't found a good way to solve his problem yet.

#### Simpler problem:

Say we want to do the same only for the files that are **currently** reachable on the current branch under a **given** directory within the repository.

---

Some related threads and close solutions:

- [git ls-files sort by modification time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362345/git-ls-files-sort-by-modification-time) (only files under the current folder, **but** the datetime output is **not** in human-readable format)

Comment: This is going to be some very straightforward awking on something like `git log --name-only --pretty=%x0a%cD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demand to list all the files in the repo is ambitious. All the files reachable from all the refs or just from HEAD or just from one or more specific branches? To simplify it, I assume it's HEAD.

```
git log HEAD --pretty="/invert:%h" --name-only | grep -v -E "^\/invert:|^$" | sort -u | while read path;do echo $(git log -1 --pretty="%ad %h" --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -- "$path") $path;done | sort -u
```

`%ad` is author date. If you need commit date, use `%cd`. HEAD could be another branch or ref or a revision range.

If it's all the refs, try

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -i git log -1 {} --name-only --pretty="/invert:%h" | grep -v -E "^\/invert:|^$" | sort -u | while read path;do echo $(git log -1 --pretty="%ad %h" --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -- "$path") $path;done | sort -u
```

If it's all the branches, try `git rev-list --branches`. If it's some specific branches, `git rev-list --branches=<pattern>`

Updated: another way to get the changed files, `git diff <commit>^ <commit> --name-only`

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay. Very helpful. I simplified the original problem a bit. As a matter of fact, I think it's the "simpler problem" what I realized it's most useful.