# How to list "Changes not staged for commit" ordered by modification date?

Tags: git

I have a repo with a web application in it.
It was updated a few months ago, which resulted in a few thousand deleted/modified files.
Also, some minor changes have been made since then too.
I can't yet tell how many events affected how many files, but maybe only 1-2 affecting a few files each.
But nothing was ever staged/committed.

Now i want to identify groups of files to put in different commits.
I guess i can look at modification dates for that.
I think i can assume all deletes were in the big update, so i can put all those in one commit.
With the modified files, i need to identify groups of files with the same(or similar) date.

[git ls-files sort by modification time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362345/git-ls-files-sort-by-modification-time)
gave a hint which lead me to do a `git ls-files -mz | xargs -0 ls  -alt >> out.txt`
giving me a roughly ordered list. It jumps through dates as xargs works in batches i guess.
(I wrote the output to a file, as i could not get a pager (| more))

So, once i get a cleaner list, or clean the list manually, i would do something like `xargs -a file -d '\n' git add`. Sounds like reasonable?
Or is there a more direct way to do a `git add` with files of a specific date range?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a file that has not been changed does nothing, so you could just use `find` to grab files modified in a date range and pipe that to `git add`

For example, to add files modified in the last day (excluding the .git directory).

```
find . -mtime -1 -not -path "./.git" -not -path "./.git/*" | xargs -l1 git add
```

Unchanged files will do nothing, ignored files will throw a warning, but otherwise do nothing.